# Joomla 3 Как с помощью php узнать id категории в которой находится пользователь?

Tags: php, joomla

Имеем CMS Joomla 3, Как с помощью php узнать id категории в которой находится пользователь? Например если id категории 5 то показать надпись hello world.

Конструкцию if else я напишу уже сам, мне важно узнать идентификатор текущей категории.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ уже.

```
if (JRequest::getVar('view') == 'category') {
  $id=JRequest::getInt('id');
} else if (JRequest::getVar('view')=='article') {
  $id=JRequest::getInt('catid');
}
echo 'ID category - '.$id;
```